# check if a torch tensor is an integer tensor

Tags: python, torch

What is the easiest way to check that a torch tensor’s dtype is an integer type?

I ultimately don’t care if it is `torch.uint8` or `torch.int32` for example, I just want to know if it contains integers.

I also don’t care on which device it is located

I could write something like

```py
tensor.dtype in (torch.int8, torch.uint8, torch.int16,...)
```

But I was wondering if there was a more elegant way

Comment: There seems to be no good way. Can you accept `not tensor.dtype.is_floating_point and not tensor.dtype.is_complex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are `torch.is_floating_point(...)` and `torch.is_complex(...)` enough?

```
# True
torch.is_floating_point(torch.tensor([1.2]))
# False
torch.is_floating_point(torch.tensor([1]))
```

Comment: Alright I wasn’t aware of is_floating_point … Thank you!